# How to loop through different config files one at a time?

Tags: python

I want to train a ML model with different configurations. I have a few config files in the config folder and hope to keep testing them one after another so that I don't have to wait for each training to finish and manually run `train.py` each time.

I thought I could just use a for loop like this:

```py
from train import train_on_config

configs = ['config1.cfg', 'config2.cfg', 'config3.cfg']

for config in configs:

    train_on_config(config)
```

Since each run of `train_on_config(str: config)` would take hours, my concern is that if the for loop is going to wait for each run to finish or will it iterate through configs right away and have all 3 runs of train_on_config at the same time, which in my case I would like to avoid.

I am aware of cron for Linux, but that seems to only to schedule regular occurrances, not one after another for different configs...

Overall, I just want to make sure the for loop will run `train_on_config(str: config)` one at a time.

Comment: Yes your models will be trained one by one. But make sure that they are not overwritten when saving. But I don't understand why you want to run them one by one, if you don't want to wait. Wouldn't it be better to train them in parallel?

Comment: Your loop will finish the 1st config before moving onto the next unless you build in some kind of threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is executed sequentially. Each call will execute after the previous one finishes.